# Tuple of Pairs from List of Integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a list of tuple pairs from a list of integers. The list of tuple pairs will contain pairs of numbers found in the list. Example below:

```
listofint = [4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2]
listoftuplepairs = [(3,3),(1,1),(2,2),(1,1)]
```

I am confused how I can implement this using a list comprehension. I have tried this below but it only returned an empty string.

```
listoftuplepairs = [(i,listofint.remove(i)) for i in listofint if listofint.remove(i) == i]
```

I understand using `remove()` on a list does not return anything. I have experimented with `pop()` but I can only pass to it a list index as the argument, instead of the actual value I want to `pop()` and store in my list of tuples.

Is there any other way to do this via list comprehension?

Comment: What would the output if `listofint = [4, 3,1,3,3, 1, 2, 3, 1]`?

Comment: `listoftuplepairs = [(3,3),(1,1),(3,3)]`. It finds which number has a pair and creates a tuple from it, then adds it to the `listoftuplepairs`.

Comment: The order of the output matters?

Comment: Not really. But I was assuming that would be the order if I were to traverse to each element. So I would remove first element, find its pair in the list, add it to the tuple, delete it from list. Then start all over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

`Counter` is used to count the number of occurrences of hashable objects.

```
from collections import Counter
l=[4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2]
c=Counter(l)
# Counter({4: 1, 3: 3, 1: 4, 2: 3, 5: 1})

[(k,k) for k,v in c.items() for _ in range(v//2)]
# [(3, 3), (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

So, here key `k` would be the number and value `v` would be the number of times it occurred in the list. Since you wanted pairs to get the number of pairs I did `v//2`.
The above approach in one-line list comprehension would be

```
[(k,k) for k,v in Counter(l).items() for _ in range(v//2)]
```

Using [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20fromkeys#dict.fromkeys). Just mimicking what `Counter` does here.

```
c=dict.fromkeys(l,0)
for k in l:
    c[k]+=1

[(k,k) for k,v in c.items() for _ in range(v//2)]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what Counter does and also what this code does? I am new to list comprehensions.

Comment: @Nico_Robin `Counter` is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. I'll add explanation to the answer. ;)

Comment: @Nico_Robin Added explanation. Hope it helped. ;) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the more thorough explanation! :) however, I still do not get the purpose of `range(v//2)` <- what does it mean?

Comment: @Nico_Robin To get the number of pairs. Say you've `v` as 5....number of pair you make from it would be 2 which is `5//2-->2`

Comment: ooh I see. So essentially your list comprehension is creating (k,k) for every k,v in the dictionary for as long as there is a pair??

Comment: @Nico_Robin I'm creating v//2 number of pairs (k,k) for every k,v.